# Android Hangouts incoming call event

Tags: android, sip, voip, google-hangouts

I am facing to a problem when it is necessary to intercept (somehow) an event when incoming call over Hangouts has place. Particularly, when there is a popup appearing over main content indicating that new voice call is received.
None of the way to catch this event were successful. I tried Broadcast Receiver and listener of the TelephonyManger but without any success.
I am wondering, does anyone has experience with it?